# How do I get executable indexed by dash/launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I've recently downloaded Eclipse package, and uncompressed it to `/home/me/Development/tools`. I'm quite new to the new Ubuntu so I'm not sure how it works. I assumed that the launcher/dash (not sure what to call it) works very similar to OS X's spotlight that automatically scans the system for files. However, every time I search for "eclipse" on the launcher/dash, the only entries I get are for the tar.gz in `~/Downloads`. How do I get the executable in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a *.desktop entry and place it in /usr/share/applications or ~/.local/share/applications.

Example:

```
# eclipse.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Exec=/home/me/Development/tools/eclipse
Name=Eclipse
Comment=Develop software with the Eclipse IDE
Icon=icon path here
```

`gnome-desktop-item-edit` from package `gnome-panel` should be able to do this for you if you don't want to create the entry yourself.